How to check if StyleBackground is set?
I want to implement some lazy initialization of a property of type StyleBackground like this:
protected StyleBackground image;
public StyleBackground Image
{
    get
    {
        if (image.value == default)
            image = LoadImage();
        return image;
    }
}

What should I check to find out whether image is already set? Is image.value the right thing? Whether I do it right checking the image.value (of type Background) for default value? Or perhaps image.keyword would be better? Like
image.keyword == StyleKeyword.Undefined

I found out - after setting the image.value, the image.keyword remains untouched (StyleKeyword.Undefined by default). So, image.keyword is not the property to check whether StyleBackground is set or not.
